# How can i select specific columns that start with a word according to a condition of another column in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this :

| date | var | cat_low | dog_low | cat_high | dog_high | Love | Friend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 1 | 7 | 13 | 19 | NA | friend |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 2 | 8 | 14 | 20 | NA | friend |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 3 | 9 | 15 | 21 | NA | friend |
| 2022-02-01 | B | 4 | 10 | 16 | 22 | love | NA |
| 2022-02-01 | B | 5 | 11 | 17 | 23 | love | NA |
| 2022-02-01 | B | 6 | 12 | 18 | 24 | love | NA |

I want to select the columns related to columns Love and Friend. If the column Love is love to give the columns that starts with cat and if the column Friend is friend to give me the columns that start with dog.

ideally i want to look like this :

| date | var | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 7 | 19 |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 8 | 20 |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 9 | 21 |
| 2022-02-01 | B | 4 | 16 |
| 2022-02-01 | B | 5 | 17 |
| 2022-02-01 | B | 6 | 18 |

```
library(lubridate)
date = c(rep(as.Date("2022-01-01"),3),rep(as.Date("2022-02-01"),3))
var = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3))
cat_low = seq(1,6,1)
dog_low = seq(7,12,1)
cat_high = seq(13,18,1)
dog_high = seq(19,24,1)
Friend = c(rep("friend",3),rep(NA,3))
Love = c(rep(NA,3),rep("love",3))
df = tibble(date,var,cat_low,dog_low,cat_high,dog_high,Love,Friend);df
```

Any help? How i can do that in R using dplyr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` try this.
The first `summarise` filters for dog or cat, the second renames and puts the variables together.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarise(date, var, 
    across(starts_with("dog"), ~ .x[Friend == "friend"]), 
    across(starts_with("cat"), ~ .x[Love == "love"])) %>% 
  rename(a = dog_low, b = dog_high) %>% 
  summarise(date, var, a = ifelse(is.na(a), cat_low, a), 
    b = ifelse(is.na(b), cat_high, b))
        date var a  b
1 2022-01-01   A 7 19
2 2022-01-01   A 8 20
3 2022-01-01   A 9 21
4 2022-02-01   B 4 16
5 2022-02-01   B 5 17
6 2022-02-01   B 6 18
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways, but here's one:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with(c("cat", "dog")),
               names_to = c("animal", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(cat|dog)_(low|high)") %>% 
  filter((is.na(Love) & animal == "dog") |
         (is.na(Friend) & animal == "cat")) %>% 
  select(date, var, low, high)
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  date       var     low  high
  <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2022-01-01 A         7    19
2 2022-01-01 A         8    20
3 2022-01-01 A         9    21
4 2022-02-01 B         4    16
5 2022-02-01 B         5    17
6 2022-02-01 B         6    18
```